# How would you design a UI for a form with selecting scheduled?

Tags: forms, gui-design, wpf

Sorry for the title, but I am a little bit exhausted here and I am not even sure if this is the right place to ask for help. I am making a Windows Desktop Application (C# WPF), it is the same as POS System, but in my case, the user needs to select a specific schedule for the transaction. One transaction can have multiple items, which means in one transaction the user can have multiple schedules per item.

To give you more examples, this is the prototype of my transaction (note: any of this is just an example)

As you can see, there were three items in this transaction. After clicking the `Date and Time` input, a modal dialog will appear, and as you can see, the modal is shown at the first transaction (assuming I clicked the first item).

The problem came after having multiple items per transaction. as you can see, I clicked on the DATE AND TIME of item six, but the dialog or the modal shown in the middle of the screen made it looks like the second item is the triggered item.

It looks bad and negative. how can I improve this? Basically what I wanted to do here is that show the schedule modal, and emphasize which item the user is focused on and is writing the schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Many ideas come to me but are all too graphic. I think the simplest, most immediate, and easiest to understand is a veil in the entire affected area with a high z-index in the elements to be highlighted:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can darken the screen and center every date/time so that no matter what item they select, it will be in the center. You can also add a header to the date/time picker with the particular's number as well as its name. Bonus if it's required to enter a particulars name BEFORE you select a date/time, otherwise you can use < blank> for any scenarios where the user selects a date/time before adding the particular's name.

Example Below:
[image]